# MySQL not saving on test_ database when testing using Django

Tags: python, django, testing

Curently I've a Django Application and it works perfect when using their models on my project. But when I try to create a new object when testing on my test.py it wont save tried debug and it returns for object.pk (None)

Here is my code:

```
class TestUserViews(TestCase):

    def test_authentication_success(self):

        try:
            cc = Country.objects.create(name="Lala Land")
            print('country saved')
            print(cc.id)
            print('-----')
        except Exception as error:
            print(error)

        try:
            ll = Language.objects.create(name="English")
            print('language saved')
            print(ll.id)
            print('-----')
        except Exception as error:
            print(error)

        try:
            user = User.objects.create(first_name="user name",
                                    last_name="user last",
                                    phone="000123455",
                                    identification="0000001123",
                                    address="my house",
                                    country=cc,
                                    language=ll,
                                    email="email@mail.com",
                                    password=hash_string("mypassword"))
            print('User saved')
            print(user.id)
        except Exception as error:
            print(error)
```

Comment: could you provide your traceback?

Comment: Testing uses a separate database which is automatically deleted when tests complete (irrespective of the actual test result). Not sure if this is what you are asking about or something else.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I know it uses another database.. exacly test_ prefix. The issue is that it wont save anything. I did --keepdb to see saved data and its empty.